# Admob placement consistency on iphone 5

Tags: ios, admob, iad

I'm using this to set the frame for my ad

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-164 -GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
```

It looks fine on a 3.5" display.  On the 4" display things were all over the place... I finally fixed everything to look fine on the 4" using the autoscaling settings.  I don't know what to do about the banner ad though.  It ends up on top of some things on the 4" display now.  I want a different setting for a 4" or 3.5" display if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for now... maybe there is a better way.

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;


if((int)screenHeight==568)
{
// adjust for iphone 5
}
else
{
// standard frame
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to specifically place the GADBannerView in relation to your screen? I feel like this might be a use case for AutoLayout (place the GADBannerView so it's always at a certain position compared another item on screen).

Comment: This does the same thing doesn't it.  Just relative to the screen instead?

Comment: Hmm yeah but I was thinking that depending how you're writing your UI this might make it so that you only have one autolayout case (one set of constraints) compared to having two separate flows for layout on two separate screens?